# Tableau, Table Calculation into Variable

Tags: maps, tableau-api, calculated-field

Here is my [workbook on Public Tableau](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/NumericBusinessRatings/TableCalculation), see below for percentage for each location, i.e. Barista - 57.14%.

How do I convert this to Calculated Field?

I wish to drag this Calculated Field to size of datapoint on a map, i.e.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a *Quick Table Calculation*, which is like a calculated field built-in in the view. You can easily double-click on it and see what the calculation does. To achieve what you're looking for, you should create a new field with this calculation and then add it to the *Size* mark.

Here follows the formula:

```
SUM([Number of Records]) / TOTAL(SUM([Number of Records]))
```

How to get the formula from a field already in the view:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what to lick on what to get formula?

Comment: I added a gif on my answer so you can see what I mean. :-)